# The variable 'crystalReportViewer1' is either undeclared or was never assigned in designer.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

When I download the project and execute it, the Crystal Report works, but it does not show up when I go to visual studio design.

namespace POSBunifu

{

partial class frmInvoice
{

```
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);

        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.crystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Name = "crystalReportViewer1";
            this.crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "";
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(819, 486);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ViewTimeSelectionFormula = "";
 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(819, 486);
            this.Controls.Add(this.crystalReportViewer1);
            this.Name = "frmInvoice";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Receipt";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmInvoice_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1;
    }
```

Error shows on this line > this.Controls.Add(this.crystalReportViewer1);

Comment: Did you figure this out?